# Delete user from QuickBlox using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, quickblox

I am stuck with a problem, I am not able to delete a Quickblox user from my controller
Can anyone help me with the code.

My controller function is

```
public function delete_customer($id)
    {

     $query = $this->db->select('quick_id')->from('tbl_customer')
                                ->where('id',$id)
                                ->get();
         $quick_id =  $query->row_array();

         $q_id  = $quick_id['quick_id'];

        $get_img_file   =   $this->customer_model->check_by(array('id' => $id), 'tbl_customer');


        $this->customer_model->_table_name  = "tbl_customer"; // table name

        $this->customer_model->_primary_key = "id"; // $id

        $this->customer_model->delete($id);


        if(file_exists($file) == 1)

            unlink($file);



        // messages for user

        $type       = "success";

        $message    = "Customer Successfully Deleted !";

        set_message($type, $message);

        redirect('admin/customer/customer_list'); //redirect page

    }
```

I need to delete the user based on the quick_id which is stored in the QuickBlox table.
How to achieve this ??? Please help me with this .

Waiting for a response................

Answer (score 2):

This may help You 
For delete the user by it's identifier you may use this 
[Quickblox](https://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Delete_API_User_by_identifier)